# Connecting *coin RPC-Server with PHP

Tags: php, rpc, bitcoin

What we have to write to IP and port to connect ? I want to use my *coin-qt as a rpc-server.

```
<?php 
require_once 'jsonRPCClient.php';
$coin = new   jsonRPCClient('rpcuser:rpcpw123@IP:PORT/');
$json =$coin->getnewaddress();        
   var_dump($json);
   echo "</pre>";  
 ?>
```

Here is my .conf file :

```
listen=1
maxconnections=32
gen=1
genproclimit=-1
server=1
rpcuser=rpcuser
rpcpassword=rpcpw123
daemon=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to connect inside your box to the bitcoin client, then you have to use:

```
<?php 
   require_once 'jsonRPCClient.php';
   $coin = new   jsonRPCClient('rpcuser:rpcpw123@localhost:8332/');
   $json =$coin->getnewaddress();        
   var_dump($json);
   echo "</pre>";  
 ?>
```

i.e: rpchost = localhost and rpcport = 8332 (default port for bitcoin). For a different altcoin, use the provided documentation.

You previously have to enable the rpcserver with these options in your conf file.

```
listen=1
server=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=rpcuser
rpcpassword=rpcpw123
rpcport=8332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: No, because I can't find which IP I have to write for Quarkcoin.

Comment: When you put the .conf file, I think that you're running the Quarkcoin client. You have to put the IP of the PC that's running the client. If it's in another computer, you have to give access with rpcallowip=<IP_WHERE_SCRIPT_IS_LOCATED> in your conf file.

Comment: `Unable to connect to http://qrk99:qrk99008866@5.47.36.162:8910' in /home/quarkwallet/public_html/jsonRPCClient.php:140 Stack trace: #0` , still don't work..

Comment: are you executing the script in the same box?

Comment: what does "box" mean ? I'm running script on a hosting, the client in my pc.

Comment: box = PC. If you're running the script on a hosting, you'll need to rcpallowip=<IP_hosting> in your conf file, and restart Quarkcoin server.